# Return Rows Where Common ID exists and Another field has differenty types in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find where there are multiple Document Types for the SAME ID#, where there is a "Final" but not a Pitch Document (it's okay to have a Pitch without a Final, but not vice versa).

```
ID      Customer       Document Type    Create Date

1001    Acme Sales      Final           01-May-2015 
1001    Acme Sales      Pitch           01-Apr-2015 
1025    XYZ Utility     Final           01-Jan-2015 
1145    ABC Solutions   Pitch           01-Feb-2015
```

So in this example, the only row that should be returned is the one for XYZ Utility.

This is what I had written, but no files are being returned.

```
SELECT ID, Customer, Document_Type, Create_Date
FROM Files 
WHERE Document_Type = 'Final' AND Document_Type != 'Pitch' 
AND
TO_DATE(Create_Date) BETWEEN '01-JAN-2015' AND '30-JUN-2015'
```

I have tried many other variations to no avail.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
select f.id, f.Customer, f.Document_Type, f.Create_Date
from (
SELECT ID
FROM Files 
WHERE Document_Type = 'Final' 
AND TO_DATE(Create_Date) BETWEEN '01-JAN-2015' AND '30-JUN-2015'
minus
SELECT ID
FROM Files 
WHERE Document_Type <> 'Final' 
AND TO_DATE(Create_Date) BETWEEN '01-JAN-2015' AND '30-JUN-2015') t
inner join Files f on f.id = t.id
```

You can use `minus` operator to do this. The inner query gets you all the id's with only `final` as document_type. You can then join back on the original tables to select the other columns.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I used the first response.  But I appreciate an alternative way of looking at it!

Answer (score 0):

Try a NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT ID, Customer, Document_Type, Create_Date
FROM Files f
WHERE Document_Type = 'Final' 
  AND TO_DATE(Create_Date) BETWEEN '01-JAN-2015' AND '30-JUN-2015'
  AND NOT EXISTS
   ( 
     SELECT * FROM Files f2
     WHERE TO_DATE(f2.Create_Date) BETWEEN '01-JAN-2015' AND '30-JUN-2015'
       AND F.id = f2.id  -- same id, but no 'pitch'
       AND f2.Document_Type = 'Pitch' 
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach is to group:

```
select ID
from T
group by ID
having
        count(case when DocumentType = 'Final' then 1 else null end) > 0
    and count(case when DocumentType = 'Pitch' then 1 else null end) = 0
```

Some people prefer to use `sum()` here but I think `count()` is a better way to express what's going on. Another variation that might work is:

```
select ID
from T
group by ID
having max(DocumentType) = 'Final' and min(DocumentType) = 'Final'
```

You didn't tell us about any other document types and such a query is likely to break when new types are introduced to the system.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I used the first response.  But I appreciate an alternative way of looking at it!